# Calcular notas en pascal, lazarus

Tags: pascal, lazarus

Después de ingresar 6 notas, obtener el promedio de las tres mejores.

Mostrar el mensaje “**Aprobado**” si el promedio es mayor o igual a 3,5 ; caso contario, mostrar “**Desaprobado**” .

Que debo de hacerle a este codigo para obtener el promedio de las tres mejores?

```
program Project1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

uses
{$IFDEF UNIX}{$IFDEF UseCThreads}
 cthreads,
{$ENDIF}{$ENDIF}
Classes
{ you can add units after this };
   var nota,n,suma,cuenta: integer;
promedio: real;
begin
suma:=0;
cuenta:=0;
promedio:=0;
write('Cuantas notas desea Ingresar?'); readln(n);
for cuenta:=1 to n do
begin
writeln('Ingrese la nota ',cuenta,':');
readln(nota);
suma:=suma+nota;
end
promedio:=suma/n;
writeln('El promedio de las notas ingresadas es: ',promedio:4:2);
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Estuve viendo el código que escribiste. Luego de calcular el promedio deberías decidir si esta o no aprobado y solo estas escribiendo el promedio.
Para sacar el promedio de las tres mejores notas, sería mas fácil hacer el ingreso de las notas en un vector luego ordenarlos, en el caso de que sea ascendente, las tres mejores notas te quedaran en la posición 6, 5 y 4.
Escribí un código para pascal como para que lo tengas en cuenta. Básicamente lo que hace es:
- Ingresa las notas en un vector mientras realiza la suma total de las notas ingresadas.
- Luego saca el promedio.
- Ordena el vector en forma ascendente.
- Toma las tres ultimas notas del vector ordenado.
- Saca el promedio parcial con esos valores.
- Muestra si esta aprobado o no, teniendo en cuenta que el promedio total sea mayor a 3.5.
- Muestra el promedio de las tres mejores notas.

```
Program Project1;
uses
    crt;
var
    Notas:array [1..6] of integer;
    PromedioT, PromedioP: real;
        Suma, i, x, auxiliar, Pausa: integer;

begin
    clrscr;
    PromedioT:=0;
    PromedioP:=0;
    i:=0;
    x:=0;
    auxiliar:=0;
    suma:=0;

    for i:=1 to 6 do
    begin
        write ('Ingrese la Nota: ');
        readln (Notas[i]);
        suma:=suma+Notas[i];
    end;

    PromedioT:= Suma/6;

    for i:=1 to 6 do
    begin
        for x:=1 to 6 do
        begin
            if (Notas[i]> Notas[x]) then
            begin
                auxiliar:=Notas[i];
                Notas[i]:=Notas[x];
                Notas[x]:=auxiliar;
            end;
        end;
    end;

    if (PromedioT>3.5) then
        begin
       writeln ('Como el promedio es mayor a 3,5 estas Aprobado');
        end
    else
    begin
        writeln ('Como el promedio es menor a 3,5 estas Desaprobado');
    end;

    PromedioP:=(Notas[6]+Notas[5]+Notas[4])/3;

    writeln('El promedio de las tres mejores: ',round(PromedioP));

end.
```